# Mi transacción en BlockChain nunca llega a su destino

Tags: transacciones, blockchain

Tengo una transacción en *BlockChain*, y está en espera por un largo tiempo, pero no puedo hacer que se complete.

¿Es posible completarla o finalizarla?, y en ese caso, ¿Cómo debo proceder para llevar a cabo esto?

La transacción es **[esta](https://blockchain.info/tx/719f78b2e6d0a8d93c8f1e4bac275d9958a7f1ae55729eade78975d604e69a6a)**.

Compruebo siempre en mi panel y siempre sigue igual:

> https://prnt.sc/ht34oo

Intente usando algun acelerador pero me encuentro en la misma situación:

Mi transaccion nunca llega.

Comment: Si la espera es de largo tiempo no, la cadena de bloques debio cerrar tu transaccion cada 10 minutos o al menos eso tengo entendido, por ende debe esar ya cerrada saludos

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Jesus!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]** en base a este documento modifica tu pregunta, es recomendable agregar lo que has intentado, saludos!

Comment: puse una foto la transaccion nunca avanza.